# Module::Build Cache Cleanup

Tags: perl

I'm using `Module::Build` to build my distribution. My distro is making a cache file in `$HOME/.cache/my_*.cache`

I need to be able to cleanup this file on module uninstall (or at least make sure it's not there during module install).

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own `clean` target, then do whatever it is you need to do. In your `Module::Build` subclass, you'd define an `ACTION_clean` method to do the work. See [Dave Rolsky's article on Module::Build for Perl.com](https://www.perl.com/pub/2003/02/12/module1.html/).

But, `Module::Build` is a dead end. It was removed from the Standard Library in v5.21 and there hasn't been significant development on it since 2017. It was an idea that never quite reached its potential. It would have been nice to have a pure-Perl build system, but build systems require a lot of maintenance. After Strawberry Perl effectively solved the Windows problem (partly by providing a `make` variant), there wasn't as much of a need for `Module::Build`.

Consider using `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`, which comes with Perl. If you have simple needs, you'll do a lot less work. In that case, you'd pass `WriteMakefile` a `clean` key with the appropriate value.

```
my %WriteMakefile = (
    ...,
    'clean' => { FILES => "$ENV{HOME}/.cache/my_*.cache" },
    );
```

Comment: Considering if I should switch to Dist::Zilla. Have not used that before, but apparently it's more powerful.

Comment: I'm not a fan of Dist::Zilla, but I suggest first doing everything by hand, then considering if the things you find yourself doing would improve with some other tool, dzil or otherwise.

Comment: What do you use?

Comment: I don't use anything like Dist::Zilla. I typically avoid any tool that requires someone else to use the same tool.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the idea. I ended up creating a subclass of Module::Build with the necessary cleanup:

```
    my $class = Module::Build->subclass(
    code => q{
        sub _clear_cache {
            for ( glob "$ENV{HOME}/.cache/my_pod*.cache" ) {
                print "Removing: $_\n";
                unlink or warn $!;
            }
        }
        sub ACTION_install {
            my ($s) = @_;
            $s->_clear_cache;
            $s->SUPER::ACTION_install;
        }
        sub ACTION_clean {
            my ($s) = @_;
            $s->_clear_cache;
            $s->SUPER::ACTION_clean;
        }
    },
);

my $builder = $class->new( ...
```